# Route is not defined?

Tags: json, ajax, laravel

I have the following code:

```
data: function(row, type, val, meta) {
    return tmpl('<%if(slug){%><a href="<%=route("url-show-event", slug)%>"><%=title%></a><%}else{%>-<% } %>', row);
    },
```

It's part of a datatables ajax call.

The problem is that I get this error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: route is not defined

I've uploaded to my server and there is correctly working, but not in localhost

So I've deleted all vendors from Laravel and install and update, but I still get the same error.

Any idea?

Comment: which version you are using?

Comment: Laravel 5.5.40 in both, server and localhost

Comment: ```url-show-event``` is exists? post your routes please

Comment: Route::get('/entradas-{slug}/{token?}', 'EventsController@show')->name('url-show-event');

Comment: The thing is that it's correctly working in production but not in localhost, same code, same database so it's weird, that's why I was trying with composer install to see if the problem was about vendors. The other option is that in localhost route is treated differently

Answer (score 1, accepted):

boss, try this php artisan view:clear, sometimes help

Answer (score 1):

```
php artisan config:clear

php artisan route:clear

php artisan cache:clear
```

It may happens when you have cached routes. clear the cache and try again.